# New image dropper is not working

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, links, image

The new imgur-based image dropper is not working.

The image URL works (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tI9Q.jpg), but the embedded link does not.

See my post: [Advantages of a deadblow hammer?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191324/advantages-of-a-deadblow-hammer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding 4 spaces to the beginning of a line makes it a [**code block**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

```
Click 'edit' to see the four spaces before this line.
```

It is useful on the programming sites (e.g., StackOverflow) where there is [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) enabled on those (something we don't have/need here).

I've deleted those 4 spaces & the picture now appears.